# наложение одного изображения на другое

Tags: css

[image: надо вставить изображение снизу в красную фигуру при помощи библиотек php]
я новичок в этой области, не могу разобраться как вставить изображение(растянуть его по красной фигуре)

[image: изображение, которое надо вставить]

Comment: надо реализовать при помощи библиотек php

Comment: Не выдумывайте лишнего.. Не нужны тут никакие библиотеки, достаточно 'css3 transform' (в теории transform, так-то я в сss3 не особо шарю)

Comment: нужна деформация или просто маска?

Comment: Вот Вам растянуть по красной фигуре. Но зачем синий прямоугольник здесь?! Я сегодня точно не усну - буду доискиваться! :)

Answer (score 1):

Я в этом случае воспользовался inkscape так как он мне удобен просто но можно использовать adobe illustrator, corel draw, или любой другой векторный редактор

Я нарисовал нужный контур ..сначала сделал прямоугольник и без добавление точек согнул верхние и нижние грани бывшего прямоугольника

Скопировал вашу картинку из вопроса и поставил её на pattern и в качестве заливки применил этот pattern , получилось вот это ..

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 542 251" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" width="542.39502" height="260.444"  patternTransform="translate(.05 -10)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="542" height="260" image-rendering="optimizeSpeed" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhhV0.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>

 <path d="m0 51c227-80 377-54 542 0v200c-232-76-365-40-542 0z" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
</svg>
```